# Conversion from mjpeg to mp4 (libx264) with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, html5-video, mjpeg, libx264

If you convert from mjpeg to mp4 (libx264) with FFmpeg,
Playback can not be performed on Windows · Mac.

Thumbnails are not displayed on the icon.
However, with the HTML5 Video tag, playback is possible.

Why? Please tell me if you understand.
Thank you.

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.mov -b 4000k -vcodec libx264 destination_file.mp4
```

Comment: Play with the Safari browser on the iPad failed.

Comment: you might want to specify a specific transcode for the audio as well (eg `-c:a aac`), and make sure your ffmpeg is a current version

Answer (score 10):

The usual reason for this is the pixel format. The MJPEG may have 4:2:2 or 4:4:4 chroma sampling which most players don't support in H264. So try

```
ffmpeg -i source_file.mov -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v 4000k -c:v libx264 destination_file.mp4
```